# Can't connect to SQL Server with a created web service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to teach myself some basics on web services and set up a simple app that just accesses SQL server and pulls an item from the database.

But I get this error when trying to connect:

" Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found"

I use this connection string for other solutions and it works fine, but not for the web service, and when searching Stack I can't find solutions that fit this issue.

```
      <connectionStrings>
<add name="Snafoo" connectionString="Data Source=HOCHBAUM|SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Snafoo;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And here is the web service:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;


    namespace SnafooWebService
    {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for SnafooService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "Snafoo")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SnafooService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod()]
    public Snacks GetSnackByID(int ID)
    {
        //Retrieve connection String from Web.config
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Snafoo"].ConnectionString;
        //Create a SQL connection object
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            //This object executes stored procedure in SQL
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSnackByID", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@Id", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            Snacks snack = new Snacks();
            //Opens the cconection
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //Retrieve column values and populate properties of snack object
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                snack.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                snack.name = reader["name"].ToString();
                snack.location = reader["location"].ToString();

            }
            return snack;

        }

    }

}
    }
```

Comment: "HOCHBAUM|SQLEXPRESS" seems wrong, try "HOCHBAUM\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: And you have the answer!  It worked!  Stared at it for hours and totally missed that, good to have those second set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

in Case you are not using Local SQL Server 
1-Check your Services if the SQL Browser is Started 
2-On your SQl Server configuration manager Check if you enabled TCP/IP and Name-pipes to be able to access your database remotely  
3-if your sql server is not local you can access it by using the IP and Port such as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS,1029 , where you can change the Port from your sql configuration manager. 
4-make sure in your connection string you put the username and password ( uid=sa;password=mmmm) 
hope those notes will help you